# Why doesn't my input button change height?

Tags: html, css

I can't change the size of my input button. Can anyone explain why?

```css
#reset{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxa60aj6/)

Comment: I'm trying to make the button height bigger.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue, what browser are you using.  Altering the height via CSS works as intended.

Comment: I got it, it's because my browser has default button settings.

Comment: Your proof of concept is profound.  May I please practice and build upon it?  The utilization of `for(;;) {}` `.width()` `.height()` and `.appendTo()` methods to excecute a large task so quickly.

I will use it, preferably to make a simple reveal the message or show the picture app.  To practice as well.

Comment: For sure, go for it!

Answer (score 3):

By default the styling of input elements would be based on the user's operating system's theme. You have to override that with the following to remove the defaults.

```
input[type="button"]{
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxa60aj6/1/